# What is the availability percentage for AWS VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

In order to calculate overall system availability of my architecture having couple of EC2 instances and EFS, where the EC2 instances and EFS use VPC (each in separate subnet), do I have to be concerned with the availability percentage of the AWS VPC?

What is the availability percentage for AWS VPC?

Comment: A VPC is a logical "linking together" of resources. It doesn't actually exist physically. While individual resources (eg EC2 instances) might have issues, I don't recall seeing a situation where the VPC service itself has had a failure.

Answer (score 1):

AWS regions are distributed amongst a number of logical data centres, these are called availability zones. Each availability zone has its own isolated power and water as well as being located in different locations within a few KM of each other.

When you create a subnet within a VPC you decide the availability zone it will reside in. To ensure your application is highly available it is best practice to distribute subnets across each availability zone.

By doing this you should be able to withstand a single availability zone going down, meaning that your application should still maintain uptime.

For more information take a look at the [Regions and Availability Zones](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regions_az/) documentation.

Comment: Does the same apply for elastic services like ELB, EFS, SQS as I see that in architecture planning diagrams these instances are not replicated to increase availability; unlike EC2 where  multiple instances are required to increase availability.

Comment: For services that reside within a VPC such as ELB and EFS you specify the subnets that it is distributed in. For services that reside within the region but not the VPC such as SQS AWS will manage their distribution across AZs.

Answer (score 1):

To estimate availability for any AWS architecture, make sure and check the service level agreement AWS provides for each service.

From https://aws.amazon.com/compute/sla/

> AWS will use commercially reasonable efforts to make the Included Services each available for each AWS region with a Monthly Uptime Percentage of at least 99.99%, in each case during any monthly billing cycle (the “Service Commitment”). In the event any of the Included Services do not meet the Service Commitment, you will be eligible to receive a Service Credit as described below.

As you can see, for compute services AWS provides 99.99% uptime.

Each service will have its own SLA.

For SQS see https://aws.amazon.com/messaging/sla/

For EFS see https://aws.amazon.com/messaging/sla/

For a complete list of AWS SLAs see https://aws.amazon.com/legal/service-level-agreements/

Comment: I often see that architectures have multiple EC2 instances to improve availability. But services like ELB/EFS/SQS are always one per region. Why is that. Does AWS automatically handle the replication of these services?

Comment: Also in your answer you have not given any reference regarding the availability percentage of VPC

Comment: There is no such SLA for a vpc. Only services that run in a vpc have declared uptime SLAs.

Comment: Yes SQS and others are managed services, and have redundancy built in. You don't need to manage it directly.

Comment: Ok so the only way to make SQS more reliable is to have it (the entire architecture setup) configured in multiple regions.